# "Forward" a directions request from MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, ios6, mkmapview, mkannotationview, ios6-maps

I have a MKMapView with a few Annotations. I would like to add the option to "forward" the user to the native Maps (iOS6) app for directions to the selected annotation from within the callout "pop-up"...

Is this possible? Maybe using a pseudo-link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it is possible to implement according to this article:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html